# GKE - Is it a way to customize network endpoint name?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I created clusters for production and staging. You know those configuration should be same as possible.

When I created Network endpoint groups for each clusters, those name are much alike and I cannot distinguish them by heart.

See first and last one:
[image]

In the document,
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#create_a_service

> The NEG's name has this format: `k8s1-cluster-uid-namespace-service-port-random-hash`

So, my options are change `namespace` or `service name`, but changing those names make unwanted differences in production and staging environment setup.

Are there any idea about solving this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#validate_neg_creation) says the name of the NEG was generated automatically using the formula:

> k8s1-cluster-uid-namespace-service-port-random-hash

So, you only can modify the name if you modify some of this items:

- Use a different cluster (as you already have)
- Modify the namespace
- Modify the service-name

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you know this doesn't resolve my problem sorry.

Comment: yes, but it is not possible to change the NEG's name